# Java Compound Operator

Tags: java, operators, compound-operator

I have a loop for palindrome checking and I want to ask why does it work when i do

```
b=b*10+a
```

but when I do

```
b*=10+a
```

it doesn't work even though it's short for `b=b*10+a`.

```
int a=0,b=0;

while (number>0) {
    a=number%10;
    b=b*10+a;
    number/=10;
}

int a=0,b=0;

while (number>0) {
    a=number%10;
    b*=10+a;
    number/=10;
}
```

Comment: `b=b*10+a ` and `b*=10+a` are not equivalent. `b*=10+a` is equivalent to `b = b * (10 + a)`.

Comment: Hint: when you do not understand what your code is doing: then PRINT intermediate steps, or learn how to use a debugger. It is that simple. For such simple code you do not need other people to tell you what is going on. And note: when asking for "not working code" then always follow [mcve] and give expected vs actual output.

Answer (score 0):

Because those are two completely different operations.

Let's say b=5 and a=2, then

```
b=b*10+a
```

is going to set b = 52, ( (5*10) + 2)

```
b*=10+a
```

is going to set b = 60, (5 * (10+2))

Answer (score 0):

```
b=b*10+a
```

computes `b*10 + a` and assignes the result as the new value of `b`.

```
b*=10+a
```

is equivalent to

```
b = b * (10 + a)
```

so it computes `b * (10 + a)` and assigns the result as the new value of `b`.